# Get MDX generated by Excel cube formulas

Tags: excel, mdx, aspose-cells

I have a requirement to open excel workbooks in a web environment, rendered using a third part excel emulator (Aspose cells). This works fine until I hit workbooks which use cube formulas (CUBEMEMBER, CUBEVALUE etc),  The Aspose product (and the same is true for every other third party excel rendering engine) does not support cube formulas.  So, as a workaround, Aspose lets me implement a custom excel formula engine and intercept calls to cube formulas during processing. I can then attempt to recreate the corresponding MDX which Excel would have generated based on the cube formula name and parameters, and then manually execute the same queries using the dot net framework.

My question is, can anyone help with a method for trapping the mdx generated by Excel when it processes a cube formula? I know with pivot tables pointing to OLAP cubes, using VBA it is possible to capture the mdx generated by switching measures and dimensions.  Is there an equivalent thing with cube formulas in Excel?  Or is my only option to sniff activity on the cube when my workbook is processed using Excel?

Thanks in advance (hopefully).